# Slow insert performance on sharded MongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb

I'm have trouble with slow insert performance on a sharded cluster.  My setup consists of 5 shards and each shard has at least 3 replica set members.  As far as network topology goes, one group of RS members is living in Rackspace Cloud, the rest are on AWS.  Running 2.4.6 on all

I'm processing a file in Java and writing it to MongoDB.  Each file is ~60MB and the resulting data for a file ends up as ~160MB in the DB.  I'm connecting to a mongos from my Java application.   I'm sharding on the hash of the _id (auto-generated ObjectID) and I have write concern set to UNACKNOWLEDGED.

If I write to an unsharded collection I can write the whole file in ~90 seconds.  If I write to a sharded collection it's taking me ~20 minutes!

I've done some initial debugging so far:

- I've tried creating a new collection and writing to it
- I've tried disabling the balancer to ensure that there were no migrations slowing things down (I've confirmed that the balancer is disabled)
- Don't see anything strange going on in the mongos or mongod logs

Things I've noticed:

- The primary node on the primary shard is sitting at almost a constant 80% write lock.  The other primaries are hovering around 5% with occasional spikes to 30%.  The secondaries are all sitting around 5% with occasional spikes to 15%
- sh.status() shows even chunk distribution but db.collection.stats() shows that the primary shard has a count & size that's twice as big as the other four shards
- No other noticeable errors in the logs or MMS

Any ideas on how I can further debug this issue?

Update with output from sh.status()

```
                    prod.collection
                    shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
                    chunks:
                            rs1     8
                            rs2     8
                            rs3     8
                            rs4     8
                            rs0     8
                    too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
```

And the output from collection.stats()

```
mongos> db.collection.stats()
{
    "sharded" : true,
    "ns" : "prod.collection",
    "count" : 879837,
    "numExtents" : 76,
    "size" : 2210698416,
    "storageSize" : 2653114368,
    "totalIndexSize" : 73526768,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 31526656,
            "_id_hashed" : 42000112
    },
    "avgObjSize" : 2512.6226971586784,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "nchunks" : 20,
    "shards" : {
            "rs0" : {
                    "ns" : "prod.collection",
                    "count" : 300130,
                    "size" : 754047552,
                    "avgObjSize" : 2512.403131976144,
                    "storageSize" : 873058304,
                    "numExtents" : 17,
                    "nindexes" : 2,
                    "lastExtentSize" : 232005632,
                    "paddingFactor" : 1.0000000000001465,
                    "systemFlags" : 1,
                    "userFlags" : 0,
                    "totalIndexSize" : 24037440,
                    "indexSizes" : {
                            "_id_" : 9753968,
                            "_id_hashed" : 14283472
                    },
                    "ok" : 1
            },
            "rs1" : {
                    "ns" : "prod.collection",
                    "count" : 139598,
                    "size" : 350820064,
                    "avgObjSize" : 2513.07371165776,
                    "storageSize" : 470589440,
                    "numExtents" : 15,
                    "nindexes" : 2,
                    "lastExtentSize" : 127299584,
                    "paddingFactor" : 1.000000000000052,
                    "systemFlags" : 1,
                    "userFlags" : 0,
                    "totalIndexSize" : 11626272,
                    "indexSizes" : {
                            "_id_" : 5060944,
                            "_id_hashed" : 6565328
                    },
                    "ok" : 1
            },
            "rs2" : {
                    "ns" : "prod.collection",
                    "count" : 149987,
                    "size" : 376944272,
                    "avgObjSize" : 2513.179622233927,
                    "storageSize" : 470593536,
                    "numExtents" : 15,
                    "nindexes" : 2,
                    "lastExtentSize" : 127299584,
                    "paddingFactor" : 1.0000000000000484,
                    "systemFlags" : 1,
                    "userFlags" : 0,
                    "totalIndexSize" : 12713680,
                    "indexSizes" : {
                            "_id_" : 5674144,
                            "_id_hashed" : 7039536
                    },
                    "ok" : 1
            },
            "rs3" : {
                    "ns" : "prod.collection",
                    "count" : 140235,
                    "size" : 352293776,
                    "avgObjSize" : 2512.167262095768,
                    "storageSize" : 377905152,
                    "numExtents" : 14,
                    "nindexes" : 2,
                    "lastExtentSize" : 104161280,
                    "paddingFactor" : 1.0000000000000422,
                    "systemFlags" : 1,
                    "userFlags" : 0,
                    "totalIndexSize" : 11863376,
                    "indexSizes" : {
                            "_id_" : 5110000,
                            "_id_hashed" : 6753376
                    },
                    "ok" : 1
            },
            "rs4" : {
                    "ns" : "prod.collection",
                    "count" : 149887,
                    "size" : 376592752,
                    "avgObjSize" : 2512.5111050324576,
                    "storageSize" : 460967936,
                    "numExtents" : 15,
                    "nindexes" : 2,
                    "lastExtentSize" : 124985344,
                    "paddingFactor" : 1.000000000000043,
                    "systemFlags" : 1,
                    "userFlags" : 0,
                    "totalIndexSize" : 13286000,
                    "indexSizes" : {
                            "_id_" : 5927600,
                            "_id_hashed" : 7358400
                    },
                    "ok" : 1
            }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Balancer status:

```
mongos> !sh.getBalancerState() && !sh.isBalancerRunning()
true
```

Comment: if your chunks are evenly distributed, it's highly unusual that the data is *not* evenly distributed.  are you use that (a) your shard key is _id hashed, and that chunks for this collection are evenly distributed across the shards?

Comment: by the way, how do you measure that it takes 90 seconds to write to unsharded collection? You are using UNACKNOWLEDGED so are you actually checking that all writes have completed outside of your app?

Comment: Please see my updates with the output from sh.stats() and db.collection.stats().  I was writing to the unsharded collection with write concern set to SAFE which is how I know that the writes were completing successfully.  Either way, 65k documents/150MB of data shouldn't be taking 20 minutes.

Comment: agreed - what do the logs show while the slow insert is running - usually all operations that take longer than 100ms are logged, so it seems there should be lots of them, if it's taking that long.

Comment: you say you have 65K documents, but stats is showing 880K - are you re-inserting the same set of documents (just letting new _id values be generated) in each test?

Comment: The logs are showing occasional long inserts (Sun Oct 27 00:35:43.796 [conn71771] insert prod.collection ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:245972 123ms).  I'd say maybe 1% of the total inserts are crossing the 100ms threshold.

Comment: Can you also try the normal (SAFE/ACKNOWLEDGED) for the sharded run? I suspect you may be getting errors on the slow run that aren't being caught.

Comment: I'm using this collection to process multiple files, I've processed 12 unique files as I've been working on this today.  All the _id's are generated by MongoDB

Comment: Thanks Asya, I will try to run with SAFE/ACKNOWLEDGED and report back if I get any error.

Comment: this isn't the best forum to debug this issue, but one more comment - your stats indicate something other than just insert activity, are you also updating the documents in this test?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40058/discussion-between-mason-and-asya-kamsky)

Comment: We too see very slow insert speed as compared with unsharded collection. Usually bulk save is too slow on sharded as I think without sharding it's pushing whole set of documents to then end. And with sharding it's actually push to mongos and then mongo is distributing based on shard key. So overhead is added